# Flutter: trigger alarm when app is killed/terminated

Tags: flutter

How to implement an alarm app in flutter that can trigger an alarm even if the app is killed/terminated?

I am using `workflowmanager` and the alarm is triggered when the app runs in the background, but not when I manually close the app.

Comment: Hi, did u find a solution for this?